# AlertDialog from another class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In mainActivity I have

```
public void showDialog(String title, String message, String accept, String denied){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setPositiveButton(accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(denied, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}
```

It works inside main activity, but I am traing call this from another activity, so I wrote

```
MainActivity o = new MainActivity();
o.showDialog("t", "t", "t", "t");
```

And app is crashing. I tried also wrote "this", "getAplicationContext()" instead of "MainActivity.this".

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace or Exception that you get from logcat?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uPLAfGP.png

Answer (score 0):

> It works inside main activity, but I am traing call this from another
>   activity, so I wrote
>
> MainActivity o = new MainActivity(); o.showDialog("t", "t", "t", "t");

you shouldn't use the `new` operator on classes that extends `Activity`. 
Back to your problem, it looks to me like you want to minimize the repeating code. One way, in your case could be an utility class, which contains your `showDialog` method. Its signature would be slightly different because you need a `Context` object to instantiate the builder:

```
public final class Utility { 

public static void showDialog(Context context, String title, String message, String accept, String denied){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setPositiveButton(accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(denied, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}

 private Utility() {}
}
```

Note also that the class Utility, has a `private default constructor`, which means that you can't explicitly instantiate it.

and the you can use like:

```
  Utility.showDialog(ActivityName.class, "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd");
```

Comment: The secend activity is extending from MainActivity, not Activity. Maybe it is the reason?

Comment: no it not., in this case you should be able to call `showDialog`, without instantiating MainActivity. Just write `showDialog("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd");` in your `SecondActivity` and it should work

Comment: But doesn't work :( And I can't use ActivityName.class, becouse method needs context and suggests me to change context to smth like MainActivity class

Comment: if you have `SecondActivity extends MainActivity`, calling only `showDialog("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd");` will work, **without using new MainActivity**

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong but also if I try to get app version by calling method from main activity which returns PackageInfo app is going to crash...

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Blackbelt's answer.

But just to follow up since OP wants to use it in another activity, you would use it in another activity like this. Say you wanted to use it in an activity called `SecondActivity`:  `Utility.showDialog(SecondActivity.class, "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd");`